# Create router using .NET MicroFramework

Tags: ethernet, .net-micro-framework

I'm really interested in getting started with embedded software development. Since I already understand OS internals and computer architecture, I'm thinking of starting with .NET MicroFramework (mf) vs arduino (C based). What I'm really interested in doing is creating a home firewall/router. So far I've figured out that I need a multi-port switch controller with MAC/PHY built-in along with ethernet magjacks. The final part is hooking the controller up with a processor (arm cortex maybe) running .net mf. What I'm Not sure about is how the router will handle layer-3 routing? is it all done by the processor? or are there microcontrollers available that have layer-3/layer-2 support built into them already? If its the later, then I should easily be able to put a system together using .NET MF and the router's performance shouldn't be affected as all the grunt work is being done by the microcontroller?

Comment: This question seems a bit borderline to me, it seems quite high level programming...

Comment: its related to microcontroller programming and hardware resource constraints...so definitely not something an ordinary developer can comment on.

Comment: In fact I'm not condamning or so, just wondering who could hold the answer :)

Comment: Not to mention, .NET MF is not the right basis to build a router in my opinion. It's a limited API especially in the networking area is just one reason.

Comment: .NET MF will hold you back. It's a crutch to be able to continue to use .NET in a world that it's almost always not appropriate for. In fact, I believe I have ALWAYS heard of someone wanting to use .NET MF in the context of someone who doesn't know what they're doing wanting to use something familiar. I can't remember anyone actually selecting .NET MF as the correct solution for the task. While you could say the Arduino environment is a crutch as well I suppose, there's a MUCH clearer path from Arduino to professional embedded work. It prepares you in the right way, in my opinion.

Comment: I started with Basic Stamps, and quickly switched to PIC-compatibles (Ubicom SX chips) writing ASM (because a C compiler cost money). I'd suggest starting with Arduino, then moving on to something like the MSP430 launchpad. (The MSP430 has an excellent development environment once you're used to embedded basics)

Comment: @kenny thats why I'm thinking of using a switch controller or possibly layer-3 controller as well. Those chips are designed to take care of majority of the work, so the work left for .net mf code would be to process config webpages and sending update table commands to the microcontroller.

Comment: @darron The reason I'm opting for .NET mf is the minimal ramp-up time + the ability to debug code using breakpoints. Since this is not for a production system and more of an learning/engineering exercise. I'm more interested in getting this to work, once I have this done, then obviously I can switch to Arduiono. I just think that with no embedded experience, going straight with arduino might increase the workload and extended this *hobby* project quite a bit.

Comment: @darron Another reason for going with .NETMF is the built-in GUI support. Since at some point, I'd like to mess around with a touch-screen display and UI...it'll be nice to do it using .netmf.

Comment: @tunafish24 As I said on another thread, just about all decent microcontrollers let you debug with breakpoints. It's -almost- a must-have feature for me, I think very hard before I commit to any microcontroller without debug (and usually regret it if I do pick one without).

Comment: What's this got to do with electrical engineering?  I can't take this question seriously as being about code that touches hardware when .NET is mentioned.  I may be able to comment on what parts of the stack is in hardware/firmware/software, but no I'm not going to look up exactly which ones layers 2 and 3 are.  More evidence this is a high level software question.

Comment: @darron, look at SDCC - Small Device C Compiler.  I use it for PIC.  Supports a variety of others as well.

Comment: I think you need to start with this question first: **How do I build a home-made network router with a firewall?**  and then follow up with: **Given the requirements of a network router, does the .NET MF offer enough components to fulfill them adequately?**  If you're absolutely convinced that you want to start the other way around, you can try writing a software router/firewall in .NET on your PC first and see if any of that can transfer well to a .NET MF platform.

Comment: @Tevo D: Yeah, I've used that before for 8051s. SDCC PIC support is "in progress", but PIC12 (what I needed recently) isn't on the list so far.

Comment: The PIC16 port (16 bit words basically the 18F series) has been working well for me.  I have not used the PIC14 port (16 series, some 12's).  It is not as far along and "is not yet mature and still lacks many features. However, it can work for simple code" according to their docs (http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/doc/sdccman.html/node112.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with network processors is that you will find cores that have functionality well suited for routers but they cannot do everything without help from processor/software intervention. The best I've seen is that you can set up the streams and allow the streams to be routed autonomously but the initial setup of the stream all has to be processed in a traditional way. This is most likely due to the large number of variables about the routing/firewall configuration that just isn't feasible in an ASIC. The processor will have to look at the packet and check against any firewall rules, apply any NAT or port translations and then inform the network processing to allow the stream and what modifications to make to the packet. Once these rules are in place, a well designed network processor can manage to do near wirespeed Ethernet with no processor intervention. I know Infineon and Marvell both had asics that would do this level of work but I haven't looked at either portfolio in quite some time. I doubt you will find these features in any bare minimum hobbyist type micro though.

Edit: I managed to find an example of the kind of processor I envision you hoping to get a hold of. Here's an example of a Marvel that does both GP processing as well as has hardened support for IPV6. [Marvell Avanta](http://www.marvell.com/broadband/assets/Marvell-Avanta-88f6510-Product-Brief.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I've also found a few Ethernet Switch Controllers from Micrel, that require tables to be specified and they take care of 100Mbps ethernet packet management. Although they are cheap $5, they only work at L3. This one by Marvell looks interesting, but I suspect it's going to be a bit expensive. From your experience, if you attach these network processors to a slow cpu, apart from the initial lookup and table entry procedure - it shouldn't have any effect on the performance, right?

Comment: From browsing Micrel's website they offer a full line as well. When you look at the basic parts they do nothing except move packets from an MII interface to a ethernet physical. The top end SOC's look comparable to to the Marvell chipset I linked but I looked on Digikey on the one I looked at was ~20$. The midline ethernet controllers will take a large amount of processing power to do any Ethernet work and with a micro ~70Mhz I wouldn't expect more than 3-4 Mbps. The higher end SOC type packages with processor + Hard IP would be able to do 90Mbps with less than a 70Mhz part with ideal streams.